# AspNetBoilerplate: Setting TenantId and LastModifierUserId when using a custom repository

Tags: entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

I'm building a web app with AspNetBoilerplate. I had to create a custom repository for an entity and override the `UpdateAsync` method so when I update an entity it also updates all the edited relationships (collections) of the entity, but as I'm overriding ABP default behavior the `TenantId` and `LastModifierUserId` of the parent entity and all its collections are set to `0` and `null` respectively.

The custom repository:

```
public class PersonaRepository : ABTransitRepositoryBase<Persona, int>, IPersonaRepository
{
    public PersonaRepository(IDbContextProvider<ABTransitDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }
    
    public override async Task<Persona> UpdateAsync(Persona entity)
    {
        var persona = Context.Empl_Personas
            .Include(e => e.Contactos)
            .Include(e => e.Identificaciones)
            .Include(e => e.Domicilios)
            .Include(e => e.Licencias)
            .Include(e => e.Laborales)
            .Include(e => e.Puestos)
            .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == entity.Id);
    
        if (persona != null)
        {
            // Update parent entity
            Context.Entry(persona).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    
            // delete or update entities
            foreach (var e in persona.Contactos)
            {
                var newEntity = entity.Contactos.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == e.Id);
                if (newEntity != null)
                    Context.Entry(e).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity);
                else
                    Context.Remove(e);
            }
            // Add new entities
            foreach (var e in entity.Contactos)
            {
                if (persona.Contactos.All(i => i.Id != e.Id))
                    persona.Contactos.Add(e);
            }
    
            // Update other collections
            // ...
    
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(typeof(Persona), entity.Id);
        }
    
        return persona;
    }
}
```

The entity:

```
public class Persona : Entity<int>, IAudited, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Oher properties

    public ICollection<ContactoPersona> Contactos { get; set; }
    // Other collections

    // IAudited
    public long? CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public long? LastModifierUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }

    // IMustHaveTenant
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something I need to do before `SaveChangesAsync`? If no, what should be the correct way of implementing this behavior? Should I set those fields in the AppService or in the Repository? And how can I set them easily for all the collections inside the updated entity?

Comment: Override `SaveChangesAsync` and do what you need. It is usual pattern for EF.

Comment: Call `base.UpdateAsync` before `Context.SaveChangesAsync`.